# Force whole template re-rendering when data is changed in dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer-1.0

I have this dom-repeat template in polymer

```
<template is="dom-if" if="true">
    <typeahead items="{{item.children}}"></typeahead>
</template>

<template is="dom-repeat" id="level" items="{{item.children}}">
  <li on-click="itemClickHandler" id$="[[getItemId(item)]]" class$="{{isItemSelected(item, selectedItem)}}" >
  <template is="dom-if" if="[[!toShowColumnTypeahead()]]"><span>{{getItemLabel(item)}}</span></template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="[[toShowColumnTypeahead()]]">
      <template is="dom-if" if="[[!item.searchTerm]]" restamp="true">
        <span class="f">{{getItemLabel(item)}}</span>
      </template>
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{item.searchTerm}}" restamp="true">
        <span class="">{{item.currentSearchLabel.prefix}}<span class="bold">{{item.currentSearchLabel.highlight}}</span>{{item.currentSearchLabel.suffix}}</span>
      </template>
    </template>
    <button class$="[[getItemOpenerClass(item)]]" on-click="openClickHandler" key$="[[getItemId(item)]]">Open</button>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_hasChildren(item, showChevron)}}">
      <span class="chevron"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
    </template>
  </li>
</template>
```

The data for item.children is changing from typeahead polymer component and its notifying it. however if the items.children is modified and was still part of previous result then it is `not redrawn on dom`, `I want it to be redrawn on DOM every time` there is any change in the list irrespective of whether it was part of previous change or not. Right now Polymer only redraws the changed elements on the DOM. I tried so many thing from net from `this.set` to `manually calling the render` method by `query selecting the template`.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'm not entirely sure I follow you 100% but you could try using `restamp` on the dom-repeat, forcing it to destroy and recreate elements every time item.children is changed.</strike> 
Ignore this, restamp actually only works on dom-if

Render will synchronously force rendering the changes that will usually be done asynchronously, but it only picks up changes made through the Polymer API, so you might want to make sure the changes made to your item.children are made through the Polymer API and not just native array function (i.e the thing setting it should do something along the line of this.push('theArray', newItem) instead of the usual theArray.push(newItem)).

Edit: to further clarify:

- calling render "just" forces to re render the changes synchronously, but this shouldn't force rendering more stuff than the usual asynchronous rendering
- your issue probably comes from how the array is updated. Use `this.splice`, `this.push`, `this.pop`, `this.unshift` or `this.shift` to mutate your array. [Link to the doc](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation)